# Could you recommend an image carousel?

Tags: user-interface

I have a .NET 2.0 web project. I need a simple image carousel. What I would prefer is the main image on the top, and a scrolling bar with smaller images on the bottom. When the user hovers over or clicks the smaller image, it would populate the larger image space.

If you know of anything like this, even 3rd party paid controls, please recommend them.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is the way to go here is the google search result:

http://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=jquery+image+car&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+image+carousel

Comment: but, is the jQuery library available in .NET 2.0?

Comment: It does not depend on any framework. jQuery is an independent JavaScript library which can even be used with simple HTML pages. It is JavaScript!!!

Comment: Also, it is a good idea to ask question before downgrading the answer!